# Removing keyboard focus on multiple buttons pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to hide keyboard when tapped everywhere outside of textField. So I wrapped Scaffold with GestureDetector and set onTap with unfocused(). That works well however when a button  is pressed then the keyboard is still active

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[FlatButton(child: Text('Done'), onPressed: () {})],
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('something'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            TextField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Is there any way to remove the focus without adding that unfocused in onTap of all buttons.. Reason is I've got many buttons there and some has even onLogTap set so there would be a lot of duplicate codes

Answer (score 2):

You need to also add code for hide keyboard inside `onPressed()` method of `FlatButton`

```
FlatButton(
    child: Text('something'),
    onPressed: () {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
   },   
),
```

> was hoping for some solution where I wouldn't need so many duplicate codes to do one thing.

AFAIK that is not possible because the click event of `GestureDetector` widget and click event of `FlatButton` both are different,

You are registering different/separate click event of `FlatButton` that's why your keyboard is not hiding when you click on `FlatButton`

> Now the reason why your keyboard not hiding when pressed on buttons

Because the click event of your `GestureDetector` widget if overridden by the click event of your `FlatButton`

> **SOLUTION**

You can do one thing, create a common method to hide the keyboard, and call that method to from button click

Comment: Well that what I was trying to avoid. As I mention in my question I've got many buttons on my screen and each do different things. I was hoping for some solution where I wouldn't need so many duplicate codes to do one thing. I still upvote your answer

Comment: `was hoping for some solution where I wouldn't need so many duplicate codes to do one thing.` AFAIK that is not possible because the click event of `GestureDetector` widget and click event of `FlatButton` both are different  

You can do one thing, create a common method to hide the keyboard, and call that method to from button click

Comment: Yeah I kinda was afraid of that.. creating method will make that method be called multiple times which is the same problem all over again.. I’ll wait for someone with perhaps other trick under the sleave and if there isn’t any (which I don’t think so) then I’ll mark your answer as answered

Answer (score 0):

By thinking a little outside of the box I have managed to hide keyboard on all taps by modifying GestureDetector..

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanDown: (pd) {FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();}, //<- replaced
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[FlatButton(child: Text('Done'), onPressed: () {})],
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text('something'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            TextField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now the keyboard will hide on taping everywhere outside of the TextField even on Buttons click.. No need to hide it in each button click. Please if you know about better solution then let me know

**UPDATE:**
This solution will create exception when tap on already focused TextField