# Detect a tap outside of a TextField to unfocus

Tags: flutter

I want to hide the keyboard when the user taps outside of a `TextField`. My current solution is to listen to taps in a `GestureDetector` that wraps the screen and call `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` to hide the keyboard.

The problem is that the `GestureDetector` doesn't detect taps on widgets like buttons. So when a button is tapped, the keyboard doesn't hide.

Comment: Then make a button using `Container` and wrap it inside your `GestureDetector`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: you're facing same problem as I do... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62425982/removing-keyboard-focus-on-multiple-buttons-pressed Look at my answer there.. It is a solution however a bit buggy.. I have filed an issue for that but for now is the only way to add the unfocused in all buttons

Comment: @Alok The button works alright. The problem is that the button "steals" touches from the `GestureDetector`, which is supposed to hide the keyboard on touches outside a text field.

Comment: @delmin Not sure if this would work correctly when there are multiple text fields. Tapping them should not hide the keyboard. Ideally, the gesture detector should detect taps on widgets that are not focusable.

Comment: @fhucho it works with multiple text fields. Give it a try and let me know. Problem is that it throw error when taping on selected field.. well I spent long time with it and this was the only solution I have found. Wish there is another

Comment: @delmin It kind of works. Not exactly the behavior I wanted but similar. The keyboard hides on touch down (not up) and when I tap on a different text field, the keyboard hides and show again instead of staying intact.

Comment: @fhucho that is as close as I could get. Did you get also errors in your ide when taped on already selected field? Please let me know if you find something better.

Comment: I'm getting a `NSLayoutConstraint` error in the iPhone simulator. If I had the time I would probably try to create a custom widget which detects taps on focusable widgets, perhaps by overriding the `hitTest` method in `RenderBox`.

Comment: Same as me... Well I think it is a bug and onTapDown is the way to go unless they add some other parameter into Gesture detector.. The stable channel has a lot of bugs specially with text field.. For example try to use multiple text field in landscape mode  and change focus with next button on your keyboard.. Perhaps it would be good idea to request a feature for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since Button widgets handles their own gesture, you can just add `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()` on your buttons' `onPressed()`

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    // Unfocus from any focused TextField
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    // Do button function
  },
  child: Text('...'),
)
```